# Has llm embeding-db change recently?

Tags: large-language-model

In the posting https://simonwillison.net/2023/Sep/4/llm-embeddings/
The examples for listing where the sqlite db is and what embedding collections are in it do not work.

The command  `llm embed-db collections`  and `llm embed-db path`  do not work.

This is with the latest pip install of llm 0.12 (11/22/2023).
Did this change somewhere in the last two months?

Answer (score 0):

So I studied the current Githb code.  The command is `llm logs status` and is different from the quickstart posting two months ago.

And the location on Windows is like

```
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\io.datasette.llm
```